# Подзапрос SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, оптимизация

Есть таблица результатов экзаменов по русскому языку и математике:

```
declare @Results Table
(
    SchoolID nvarchar(200),
    ParticipID nvarchar(200),
    SubjectCode int,
    TestResult5 int 
)

--subjectcode: 1-русский язык, 2-математика

insert into @Results VALUES 
        ('0001', 'Шахабов_Адам', 1, 4),
        ('0001', 'Асвадов_Аюб', 1, 3),
        ('0001', 'Майрукаев_Бекхан', 1, 3),
        ('0001', 'Шахабов_Адам', 2, 3),
        ('0001', 'Асвадов_Аюб', 2, 4),
        ('0001', 'Майрукаев_Бекхан', 2, 5),
        ('0002', 'Цуригова_Зайнап', 2, 5),
        ('0002', 'Майрукаев_Роза', 2, 4),
        ('0002', 'Муциев_Адлан', 2, 3),
        ('0002', 'Цуригова_Зайнап', 1, 3),
        ('0002', 'Майрукаев_Роза', 1, 4),
        ('0002', 'Муциев_Адлан', 1, 5)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Условие:** Необходимо извлечь список школ (`SchoolID`), у которых число участников, получивших отметку 3 по русскому языку, больше 1.

Как я это делаю:

```
select schoolid from

       (select schoolid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN subjectcode = 1 and testresult5 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) c
       from @Results       
       group by schoolid) temp_table

       where c > 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Необходимо:** оптимизировать данный запрос.

Конечно, на этом примере код выглядит не совсем большим. Я специально показал маленький пример. Все ли правильно я делаю? Можно ли как-то обойтись без **подзапроса** в этом случае?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам поможет HAVING:

```
SELECT schoolid, COUNT(ParticipID) 
FROM @Results
WHERE subjectcode = 1 AND testresult5 = 3
GROUP BY schoolid
HAVING COUNT(ParticipID) > 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe6b2/1/0

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>В дополнение к ответу **Сергея Водакова**</sub>

Если вам нужно вытащить только `schoolid` из запроса, то можно написать без `count(participid)`:

```
select r.schoolid
from results r
where r.subjectcode = 1 and r.testresult5 = 3
group by r.schoolid
having count(distinct r.participid) >= 2
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc5fe)